# will car insurance cost increase if I have accident with small payout?

Tags: united-states, car-insurance, texas

I scratched rear fender and bumper of my 2015 Mercedes s550 when I was driving inside garage. I have $1k deductible and it's gonna cost around $2.5k to repair.
Should I expect insurance cost to go up after that and how may percent it can be?

Just thinking to cancel the claim since the scratch is not too bad, but I assume it can still affect my rates in the future since they know I had accident even though the claim will have 0 payout? and it will be reported to carfax anyways?

Any recommendations if I should proceed with the claim or not (since I already reported it but I didn't request the payout yet). I have USAA insurance.

Answer (score 2):

Check your policy statement. It may say whether a safe driving discount has been applied and how much that is. Removing that would be their most likely penalty, if they do penalize you.

Go searching for the company's reputation on line and you might be able to get some indication from what others have posted, but that may not be typical and may not apply to your case.

Ask the agent who sold you the policy. They're probably your best source, assuming you don't fear telling them about the event.

But really, it's up to your insurance company. No way for us to guess without knowing which and knowing your history, and it'd only be an opinion if we did.